# how to change all words in a sentence on piglatin.java

Tags: java

I'm writing program called piglatin. The program will keep running until user type *quit*. Any words start with a vowel, the end of the word must add "way". If the word start with a consonant, then I have to move the consonant to the end of the word and add word "ay". The only problem i have is how to make my program to be able to change all the words individually instead of based on the first word of a sentence. For example *"he is nice"* should become *"ehay isway icenay"* but my output is like this *"e is nicehay"*. thank you so much for your help, i really appreciate it. here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String yourSentence="";
        String[] tokens;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter your words here: ");
            yourSentence = input.nextLine();

            if( yourSentence.startsWith("a") || yourSentence.startsWith("e") || yourSentence.startsWith("i") ||
                yourSentence.startsWith("o") || yourSentence.startsWith("u"))
            {
                System.out.print(yourSentence+ "way");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(yourSentence.substring(1)+yourSentence.substring(0,1)+"ay");
            }   
        }

        while(!yourSentence.equals("quit"));
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to split the sentence into words first, before you apply the Pig Latin rules. You should look into String#split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String yourSentence="";
        do {
            String[] words;
            System.out.print("Enter your words here: ");
            yourSentence = input.nextLine();
            words = yourSentence.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.startsWith("a") || word.startsWith("e") || word.startsWith("i") || word.startsWith("o") || word.startsWith("u"))
                    System.out.print(word + "way ");
                else if (word.startsWith("sh") || word.startsWith("ch") || word.startsWith("th"))
                    System.out.print(word.substring(2)+word.substring(0,2)+"ay ");
                else
                    System.out.print(word.substring(1)+word.substring(0,1)+"ay ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        } while(!yourSentence.equals("quit"));
    }
}
```

This also resolves multiple-letter/single-sound words, such as those beginning with "ch", "sh", and "th".  If you want to be able to correctly handle punctuation, you'll have more work to do.

I also included a new line after each line of input to tidy up the output's presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input into a String array and then loop through.

```
String[] words = yourSentence.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: You can also do `for(String word : words)`, much shorter.

Comment: If you used a standard for loop you could modify the array and then do `StringUtils.join(words, " ")` at the end. Which might make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. I split `yourSentence` in the array `token`. Then I intialised `newSentence` and used a for-loop to go through all tokens. Every item added to `newSentence` and in the end it prints this new sentence.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String yourSentence="";
        String[] tokens;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your words here: ");
            yourSentence = input.nextLine();
            tokens = yourSentence.split(" ");

            String newSentence = "";

            for(String token : tokens) {
                if( token.startsWith("a") || token.startsWith("e") || token.startsWith("i") ||
                        token.startsWith("o") || token.startsWith("u"))
                {
                    newSentence += token + "way ";
                }
                    else
                {
                    newSentence += token.substring(1) + token.substring(0,1) + "ay ";
                }   
            }

            System.out.println(newSentence);

        }

        while(!yourSentence.equals("quit"));
    }
```